# Eclipse modify classpath on its own

Tags: java, eclipse, classpath, buildpath, eclipse-classpath

I have a quite annoying issue with Eclipse and the .classpath file.
I usually used variable in my build path in order to be able to change of version easily.
The issue with Eclipse its that the software break the variables set and put the build path in lib mode instead of var.

for example from a var like that :

```
<classpathentry kind="var" path="NIAGARA_HOME/modules/platform.jar"/>
```

it destroy the kind and put it like that :

```
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Niagara/Niagara-3.7.106/modules/platform.jar"/>
```

and same thing for the JRE set :

```
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER"/>
```

to :

```
<classpathentry kind="lib" ----- etc.
```

i didn't put the whole code of the JRE since it call directly each .jar file used in my project.

How is it possible to fix it ?
First I think it come from the issue when Eclipse is starting and doesn't find the variables set and automatically destroy all relation of var into lib.

Comment: Are you using any plugins editing the classpath file? m2-plugin, or ...

Comment: Either let Eclipse do its job and don't interfere, or don't use Eclipse so you can do it your own way?

Comment: Uh, no, Eclipse doesn't normally do this. Some plug-in must be tampering with it. As @MartinBaumgartner asked, are there additional plug-ins installed?

Comment: @MartinBaumgartner Yes. We have a plugin for our work and after some tests it's the plugin that cause the issue. Thanks !